# How to get a query for child inside another child?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I am trying to get a query containing all (users/uid/order)

I tried :

```
query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").orderByChild("order")
```

And

```
query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").orderByChild("order/status").equalTo("0");
```

but they don't work for me, thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference query = database.getReference("users").child("order");

query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
         public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot item_snapshot :dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

              Log.d("item id ", item_snapshot.child("total").getValue().toString());

             }
          }
        }
```

Then you can use `query`.

Comment: Is it possible to put it to a query? Since I am trying to use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter like this

`FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Order, OrderViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Order, OrderViewHolder>(

                            Order.class,
                            R.layout.order_row,
                            OrderViewHolder.class,
                            query

                    )`

Comment: Oh sure, just updated the answer with the `query` parameter. Then you can use it inside `Adapter`.

Comment: sorry friend, I cannot assign the value to the query like in your answer.
It says the type does not match
`Required: Query` , 
`Found: ValueEventListener`

Comment: it crashed in runtime by NullPointerException now, Is it because the database reference skipped the child(aid)? Since there is a child of kid before the order.

Comment: Just use my code and see what it returns as the output. Did you add child(uid)?! Also, can i see the error? It might happen because of something else